# Adding Classes to Bootstrap popover content?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using the `html` below I can show a popover `html` button. However when adding classes to the button, the popover button will break and show on the screen. Is there a way to add classes such as `btn` to the button in the popover?

```
  <div class="col-md-2 popscustom"><a href="#x"><img data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" title="Popover title" data-content="
      <div>
         <button>Test</button>
      </div>


$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: 'hover', html: 'true', container: 'body'})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not passing data-html:"true" as a string. It needs to be a boolean...

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: 'hover', html:true})
```

Switch to single quotes (') for html content inside the popover...

```
<a href="#x"><img data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-title="foo" data-content="<div><button class='btn btn-danger'>Test</button></div>" src="//placehold.it/200"></a>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/EKuiKhFaeP